# Why is the curl command doesn't work in golang

Tags: go, ubuntu, curl

I am in the trouble when I use `golang` to run the command `curl`. My version of the `golang` is 1.15.7. The purposed is to call a API by using POST method. This is the whole command that I want to use：

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"DNS_ID":"DNS_1","Domain_ID":"Domain_1","Cell_ID":"Cell_1","Device_ID":"IOT1","IMEI":"ims-208930000000003","IPv4":"60.60.0.1","IPv6":":::60.60.0.1","Slice_ID":"121312","FQDN":"test.free5gc"}' "http://192.168.1.233:5534/current" -v
```

And this is my code so far. I used module `os/exec` in golang to run the command `curl`.

```golang
    var body string
    var FQDN string
    var content string
    var url string

    content = "\"Content-Type:application/json\""
    url ="\"http://192.168.1.233:5534/current\""
    DomainName := "test"
    IPAddress := "60.60.0.1"

    FQDN = DomainName + ".free5gc"
    body = `"DNS_ID":"DNS_1","Domain_ID":"Domain_1","Cell_ID":"Cell_1","Device_ID":"IOT1","IMEI":"ims-208930000000003","IPv4":"`+ IPAddress +`","IPv6":":::`+ IPAddress +`","Slice_ID":"121312","FQDN":"`+FQDN  +`"`

    fmt.Println(body)

    c := exec.Command("curl","-X","POST","-H",content,"-d","'{"+ body +"}'",url,"-v")

    fmt.Println(c)
    c.Stdout = os.Stdout
    c.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := c.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }
```

After I build the code and run it. The whole command is correct but seems it has some problem in the part of the `url`. The error message is like below：

```sh
/usr/bin/curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"DNS_ID":"DNS_1","Domain_ID":"Domain_1","Cell_ID":"Cell_1","Device_ID":"IOT1","IMEI":"ims-208930000000003","IPv4":"60.60.0.1","IPv6":":::60.60.0.1","Slice_ID":"121312","FQDN":"test.free5gc"}' "http://192.168.1.233:5534/current" -v
* Could not resolve host: "http
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "http
Error:  exit status 6
```

Also I have tried the command which is same as the above one in my VM. And the command curl can work. So I was wondering if it is the write way of the golang or not.
I have no idea where the error occur. Maybe it is the `""`,` or ""content"" I thought. The error message seems can't recognize the whole URL. This is just mu guess.
Hope guys can help me to deal with this problem.
Thanks a lot

Comment: The superfluous literal quotes in the strings are your problem. The quoting is interpreted and removed by the shell before `curl` runs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why build a Go app to call curl?  You can build an app in Go that does the same thing without needing to call curl

Comment: There really is no need to invoke curl: https://play.golang.org/p/xzymijN3l7L

Comment: I used HTTP before, but there are some reasons that I can not use HTTP. So I made a decision to use curl in go app. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I have modify the code with the following below. But it seems another error message is occur. The message is like: `Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because quotes are a way for `bash` to organise arguments, and since you are using Golang's `os/exec` package, there's no need to escape arguments prior to the command's execution (unless you are using `bash` in between go and the program you're trying to run):

```
var body string
var FQDN string
var content string
var url string

content = "Content-Type: application/json"
url = "http://192.168.1.233:5534/current"
DomainName := "test"
IPAddress := "60.60.0.1"

FQDN = DomainName + ".free5gc"
body = `"DNS_ID":"DNS_1","Domain_ID":"Domain_1","Cell_ID":"Cell_1","Device_ID":"IOT1","IMEI":"ims-208930000000003","IPv4":"`+ IPAddress +`","IPv6":":::`+ IPAddress +`","Slice_ID":"121312","FQDN":"`+FQDN  +`"`

fmt.Println(body)

c := exec.Command("curl","-X","POST","-H",content,"-d","{"+ body +"}",url,"-v")

fmt.Println(c)
c.Stdout = os.Stdout
c.Stderr = os.Stderr
err := c.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}
```

tl;dr: drop the quotes, everything should start working :)

Comment: Yes, it can recognized the URL. But it still can't call the API successfully. The error message  is like:  `Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: @Marrrchia try using a [JSON encoder](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) to build your JSON payload instead. Should keep everything sanitized and keep away from pesky JSON errors :)